# How to remove row from grid in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using angularjs.

I am making simple $http.delete method call in my API for deleting row from grid table:

My controller looks like below:

```
 $scope.removeRow = function(detail, index){                

       var delRes =  $http.delete($scope.appUrl + detail.id);
        delRes.success(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
            delete $scope.appDetails[index].id;
        });
        delRes.error(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    };
```

Now, API call works fine but I can still see record in my grid on UI.
When i refresh the page i can not see.
Any reason.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you are only deleting the id property of the appDetails's index row.

Try deleting the whole appDetails[index].

If that is not your problem you can try using $scope.$apply() with the proper checks before calling it. Works on async calls.

> If you're creating an AngularJS service (such as for sockets) it
>   should have a $scope.$apply() anywhere it fires a callback.
>
> $scope.$apply() should occur as close to the async event binding as
>   possible.
>   https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the selected index itmes by using [splice](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp)

### Best Way

Please try this

```
$scope.removeRow = function(detail, index){                

       var delRes =  $http.delete($scope.appUrl + detail.id);
        delRes.success(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
           var index = $scope.appDetails.indexOf(detail);
            $scope.appDetails.splice(index, 1);  
        });
        delRes.error(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    };
```

### Another way is

Rebind | reload the `$scope.appDetails` value

```
 $scope.removeRow = function(detail, index){              
    
           var delRes =  $http.delete($scope.appUrl + detail.id);
            delRes.success(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
                console.log(data);
              //Rebind the scope value 
              $scope.appDetails=data;// like call the grid load function 
               
            });
            delRes.error(function (data, status, headers, configs) {
                console.log(data);
            });
    
        };
```